# Get sourcemaps / auto-reload running in rails with compass without "compass watch"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, source-maps

So I have been researching this lately and trying out different approaches. I CAN get sourcemaps running with Sass only, still have to figure out how auto-reload should work.

Im working in a RoR-Environement with latest possible gems for Sass and Compass

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.0'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sass', '3.3.0.rc.1'
gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"
gem 'compass', '0.13.alpha.10'
```

When using compass I get this error `File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.` If i try using `gem "compass-sourcemaps", "~> 0.12.3.sourcemaps.a4836f1"` no luck, I get an app-error.

There have been suggestions on github and other sites that I could work with grunt or compass watch, this is no possible solution because I want to be able to work over the Asset-pipeline.

Any clues in the right direction would be much appreciated!

<strike>Maybe I should switch to bourbon? Would be time-consuming to go through all of my code, but I'm seriously thinking about ditching Compass :(</strike>

P.S. There have already been similar questions here on SO, but they are dated a few months back and didn't really give me any new insight.

Answer (score 2):

So since I believe this will still take some time until it will get solved by rails or any rails gem, I'll just use a transitional solution of mine:

Any compass-mixins I'm using at the moment I rewrote / wrote as my own mixin and added them to a separate file which I included. The compass-imports are commented out for the time beeing

```
/*
@import 'compass/reset';
@import 'compass/css3/transform';
@import 'compass/css3/transition';
@import 'compass/css3/box-sizing';
@import 'compass/css3/box-shadow';
*/
```

and instead I just include my own

```
@import 'my_own_writen_compass_mixins.scss';
```

(Just note that you name your mixins exactly the same as compass did, so you don't have to make any code changes.)

For my part this will do and I can carry on working on my stuff. Hope this helps if anybody is having same difficulties. Hopefully this is no long time solution ;)